# estimation for analytic stochastic processes

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, statistical-inference, stationary-processes

this is for experts in probability and stats.
There is a theorem, I have seen once:

*Given a stationary analytic random process, one can show that from the
values of a sample path in a finite interval one can estimate the variance of the process without error (i.e. estimation variance is zero)*.

Can anybody give me a reference where to find this result? I remember vaguely that it is called "theorem of B...", but the name is NOT Belyaev.

Thanks

Karl